# Как я могу посмотреть коммиты в `git log` только от одного автора?

Tags: git, git-log

Когда я использую `git log`, как я могу отфильтровать коммиты так, чтобы видеть коммиты только от заданного пользователя?

Answer (score 5):

Немного расширю [ответ @katso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582295/181472):

Во-первых, параметр `--author` принимает регулярное выражение и проверяет его вхождение в строку имени автора. Т.е. если у нас есть разрабочики Иван Петров, Семён Иванов и Геннадий Ливанов, то:

```
git log --author="Иван"
```

покажет нам коммиты, авторами которых являются первые двое. Л*иван*ов не подходит, т.к. учитывается регистр. А вот так:

```
git log --author="Иван "
```

будет найден только Иван, но не Иванов.

Во-вторых, у каждого коммита есть два "автора". Есть действительный автор внесённых изменений (author), а есть человек, который сохранил эти изменения в коммит (committer). Обычно это один и тот же человек, но коммиттер будет отличаться, например, когда вы ребейзите чужие комммиты, или когда принимаете патч по почте (и вас зовут Линус). Можно искать коммиты по второму:

```
git log --committer="Иван"
```

В-третьих, если вам нужны коммиты нескольких авторов, не нужно городить сложную регулярку. Указывайте несколько параметров подряд. То же самое работает и с `--committer`.

```
git log --author="Иван" --author="Геннадий"
```

В-четвертых, в имя автора входит и `user.name`, и `user.email`. Если нужно точное соответствие, проще искать по еmail:

```
git log --author="i.petrov@mycompany.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git log --author="Jon"
```

[log help](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

---